# expose pgbouncer service to external clients

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to implement pgbouncer on k8s, using a helm chart created deployment,service…now how do I expose the service to outside world? Not much familiar with k8s networking, tried to create an ingress resource and it created an elb in aws…how do I map this elb to the service and expose it?
the service is created with type ClusterIP…the service is a tcp service i.e. not http/https application (edited)

The helm chart used is - https://github.com/futuretechindustriesllc/charts/tree/master/charts/pgbouncer

Answer (score 1):

Ingresses are only used for HTTP and friends. In this case what you want is probably a LoadBalancer type service. That will make a balancer fabric and then expose it via an ELB.

Comment: Tried creating with servicetype as LoadBalancer but it gives this error -- 
```Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service default/pgbouncer: could not find any suitable subnets for creating the ELB```

Comment: Sounds like your Kubernetes cluster was not configured correctly for AWS. How did you deploy K8s?

Comment: Using helm chart - https://github.com/futuretechindustriesllc/charts/tree/master/charts/pgbouncer

Comment: No I mean how did you deploy Kubernetes itself?

Comment: Its using AWS EKS